# Bootstrap 3: Scaling text and images together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to scale image and text to have the same size / height using Bootstrap 3. Here's the HTML that I have:

```
<span class="col-xs-4 text-right user-menu-link-icon">
      //IMAGE GOES HERE using class="img-responsive"
</span>
<span class="col-xs-8 text-left user-menu-link-label">
     //TEXT GOES HERE
</span>
```

Here's some CSS:

```
.user-menu-link-label {
    height: 4vmin;
    margin: 0.5vh 0;
    font-size: 1.9vmin;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.user-menu-link-icon { max-width: 20vmin; max-height: 20vmin; margin: 0.5vh 0;}
```

The images are square icons that I need to have aligned to the right and likewise the text needs to be aligned to the left. Those go below each other making a column of image/text links.

The problem is that when the window becomes too small (let's say very large vertically but not very wide), the icon images are way too big compared to the text which is not the case on large screen. Attaching a couple of screenshots below.

This is how it looks on large (lg) screens:

[image]

However, as soon as the screen becomes very small (xs), it starts to look like this:
[image]

I've tried playing around with the vmin values or setting some of them to auto but I can't get it to work just right. I'm sure that's got to be a simple way to do this and I have no problem rewriting the code and CSS as long as I can achieve the desired effect.

Comment: please provide the jsfiddle link

Comment: you have a cod try please share your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems everything ok. It will be easier to use **media screen** for achieving the same effect.

Try This;

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) /*for small screen like mobile*/
{
   .user-menu-link-label
   {
      font-size: 14px /*adjust as per requirement*/
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width:401px)  /*for screen larger than mobile*/
{
   .user-menu-link-label
   {
      font-size: 16px /*adjust as per requirement*/
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use **viewport units** to specify font size.

Instead, if you don't want to use absolute units (viewport units are an example of relative units, i.e. they are relative to other values), try using `font-size` in percentages and have it modify the base font size of, lets say, your `body` element.

Like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.my-element {
    font-size: 125%; // 16*1.25 = 20px
}
```

Combine this method with [Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=media%20queries) and you'll get precise results for each use you'll ever need.